# Error when entering backend in October CMS

Tags: wamp, octobercms

I've installed October cms on Wamp with Composer. All seemed ok- I have tables in my database, but can't enter /backend. When I type file:///C:/wamp/www/october/backend (place of my project) I get blank page.

Comment: Pretty certain you'll need a http path not a file path. Go to the sites URL and add backend to that.

Comment: Hmm, I've installed october locally so I don't think I need http. Are U sure about this? Imo there's some error with installation description. But can't find it. In fact only thing U must change there, is db name in config file - which i did. Later I tryed also to load it to the site and when I run  artisan command it gives me an error : unknown database : 'database' - have no idea what it means because (as i asked on october chat) db is needed only in config file (which I entered properly) and nowhere else. .

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the PHP compiler you MUST run your site as if it were on the internet i.e. using the browser address bar and NOT click on the php file using explorer. Like this

```
localhost/october
```

or

```
localhost/october/backend
```

If you dont go via Apache then nothing will spot the `<?php` tags. It is Apache that recognises these tags and passes the script to PHP for interpretation and execution.

Comment: Ok, thx about that, but as  I didnt write before I've also tryed different paths for this project including these two U mentioned (and  a "few" more). No one was correct.

Comment: If you access it via an internet address, and you're getting a blank page, then there is a configuration issue. Check the server error logs.